# sage math software: using cli interface, is && operator(i.e. "background and control"?) functionality supported?

Tags: python, sage

I'm new to [sage math software](http://www.sagemath.org/index.html).  i've been looking though sage documentation to find if the sage cli supports any way to run multiple commands one after another, i.e. behave like bash when using the && operator. for example, on linux:

```
$ cp file1 file2 && rm file1
```

at the command line will copy file1 to file2 and after that operation is complete delete file1.  for instance i would love to be able to do something like

```
sage: g = e^-x && g && x = g
```

from a sage prompt.

Does sage support this? is there a workaround if not?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, the ";" symbol(semicolon) used in place of where i'm used to using && using bash seems to do the trick.  if there are any differences i'm not aware of, i'd appreciate the info.

Comment: `;` is equivalent to `&&` in bash. `&&` has different meanings in programming languages and math. `;` is the correct way to do it, and usually the recommended way in bash.